# Javascript/jQuery on click one element stay other disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, hide, show

How i can make when im click on one html element others disappear, for example if i had 5 pictures i click on one, and other 4 get hidden? Is there anyway to do this with for or while loop?

**EDIT** : My HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js " type="text/javascript"> </script>
</head>
 <body>

    <div id="header">
                <ul id="navigation">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>                
                </ul>
            </div>
    <center>
    <h1 class="h1">Hello User!</h1>
    </center><br /> <br/> <br/>
               <p class="category">Category 1</p>
    <hr/>
        <ul id="catitem">
                <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>                  
        </ul>

 </body>
```

When user click on

test1

im want other

gets hidden

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img_class').hide();
  $(this).show();
}
<li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">test3</a></li>
```

change your anchors
add class="img_class" to each one

Comment: Did you add the class to each anchor?